# How to take a specific line from a list in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

I have a csv table that looks like this:

My CSV table

[image]

I converted it to a list with this code:

```
// CSV route
class CSVRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const CSVRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'CSV Route',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _data = [];

  // This function is triggered when the floating button is pressed
  void _loadCSV() async {
    final _rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> _listData =
    const CsvToListConverter().convert(_rawData);
    setState(() {
      _data = _listData;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Parsing and Showing CSV"),
      ),
      // Display the contents from the CSV file
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _data.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
            color: index == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Text(_data[index][0].toString()),
              title: Text(_data[index][1]),
              trailing: Text(_data[index][2].toString()),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _loadCSV),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the button my user should tap on and the text that should change depending on the values in my table:

```
// The CSV Actions route (screen, page, etc)
class CSVActionsRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const CSVActionsRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
      const SizedBox(height: 30),
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                      Color(0xFF1976D2),
                      Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                primary: Colors.white,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Click me to change Text'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 30),


      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                      Color(0xFF1976D2),
                      Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                primary: Colors.white,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const YetAnotherRoute()),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Button 2'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 30),
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                      Color(0xFF1976D2),
                      Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                primary: Colors.white,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CSVRoute()),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Button 3'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 30),
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: <Color>[
                      // Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                      // Color(0xFF1976D2),
                      // Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Item from CSV',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

      ],
    ),
    )
    );  }
}
```

Here is a screen widget with a background that should change depending on whether the corresponding column in my list is empty.

```
// Yet another route
class YetAnotherRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const YetAnotherRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Yet Another Route'),
      ),
      body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
    image: AssetImage('files/main.jpg'),fit:BoxFit.cover
    )
    ),
        child:
        Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('Go back!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

This is the [link](https://mega.nz/file/xg51QSIA#e9cufDVBx3HjrZfhGDx_BOX3HsFFL1HfS6HIy7f3qmc) to my csv file for testing.

Now I want the following actions to be performed when that button is tapped:

1. First my users see Text1 (the first item in my list). Then they tap on the button and see Text2 instead of Text1, then Text3 and so on.
2. If the column with pictures is not empty, then users see the picture that is indicated there (for example, 01.jpg). If the column with pictures is empty, then users see the current background.
3. If the question column is not empty, then users see a pop-up message with the question listed there. Users can then make a selection (next two columns).

How to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include the link of your sample CSV file to test it out?

Comment: Oh sure! I tried to make some myself, so my file is different from the picture. However, this is not important for testing.

So here is the link: https://mega.nz/file/xg51QSIA#e9cufDVBx3HjrZfhGDx_BOX3HsFFL1HfS6HIy7f3qmc

Answer (score 0):

To get the second item text on first, you can assign the next text value by

First one **_HomePageState**.

```dart
body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _data.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    /// handle to overflow on leading, better use diff like FittedBox after trim
    final String leadingData = _data[index][0].toString();
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
      color: index == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Text(leadingData.length > 5
            ? leadingData.substring(0, 5)
            : leadingData),
        title: Text(_data[index][1]),
        trailing: Text(_data[index][2].toString()),
        onTap: () {
          if (index == _data.length - 1) {
            //skip last index or perform the operation you like
            return;
          }
          _data[index][0] = _data[index + 1][0];
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

To get image you can increase the index number a. in this 2d array `index` represent the row and `1` represent the image path.

```dart
_data[index][1]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner, so only now I understand that I took the wrong code as a basis. Specifically, I need to show text one by one on the screen. 1, 2, 3 and so on. So ListTile is not a good option.

But that's just my problem. Next time I will try to formulate my question precisely and find the closest example of what exactly I want.

However, your answer has helped me learn something new. I will definitely have a question about pictures. Once I have a sample code, I hope that you will help me.

Comment: I took this snippet from `HomePage` where you are already using `ListTile`. I am clear about your goal, you can perform this logic the way you like.

Comment: Of course. That is why I am writing that this is my problem. At that time, I had minimal knowledge, but I wanted to get something in practice. Every day I learn something new. Therefore, I am grateful to you. I will modify this code. This is all useful to me. Thanks again.